# Copying a bundle into another bundle

Tags: scala, chisel

Is there any way to copy all `bits` of a bundle into another bundle? Basically, I want to send out the same data into two outputs that would be connected to different receivers.
E.g:

```
 io.out(1).bits.x := ...
 io.out(1).bits.y := ...

 io.out(2).bits <> io.out(1).bits.clone // Hypothetical syntax
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any valid net can be assigned to another net, so for the above you could do:

```
  io.out(2).bits := io.out(1).bits
```

If you want to send the same data to multiple destinations with ready/valid interfaces, you may also want to look at [DCMirror](https://github.com/hutch31/dclib/blob/master/src/main/scala/chisel/lib/dclib/DCMirror.scala)